# Why does the handleClick method in my component seem to loop?

Tags: reactjs

I am setting out to learn some react, and I am trying to create a grid of clickable buttons. For now all I want is to change the color of the button once it is clicked.

Starting off from this [React Tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), I wrote my components to create a variable size grid through loops.
I added a handleClick method to my Grid component to change the color of the button clicked. When I click a button though, **the entire column changes colour**.

[image: The entire column changes colour when the top left button is clicked]

From the debugger it seems to pass the correct values of the indeces (i and j) to the handleClick method, so I am at a loss as to why this is happening.

The code for my components is the following:

```
var height = 3;
var width = 5;

class Cell extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <button 
        className={ this.props.value === 'ON' ? "cell cellOn" : "cell 
                    cellOff" }
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
        </button>
      );
    }
  }

export class Grid extends Component  {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          cells: Array(height).fill(Array(width).fill(null)),
        };
    }

    handleClick(i, j) {
        const cells = this.state.cells.slice();
        cells[i][j] = ( cells[i][j] === 'ON' ) ? 'OFF' : 'ON' ;
        this.setState({cells: cells});
    }


    renderCell(i, j) {     
        return(
        <Cell value={this.state.cells[i][j]} 
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(i, j)} />
        );
    }

    renderCellRow(i, w) {
        return(
        <div>
            {Array.from(Array(w), (_,x) => x).map((j) => this.renderCell(i, j)) }
        </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        const status = 'Next player: X';

        return (
            <div>
            <div className="status">{status}</div>
            <div>
              {Array.from(Array(height), (_,x) => x).map((i) => this.renderCellRow(i, width)) }
            </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Could somebody offer some suggestions? Is it because of the **map** calls that I used to loop on height and width?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way of your state initialization:

```
Array(height).fill(Array(width).fill(null))
```

I'll suggest to avoid using `fill`. It fills the array with objects by reference. So when you change one of them you get updates into the other ones.

Here is a codepen with the working version https://codepen.io/krasimir/pen/YYdLQL?editors=0010

Comment: Thank you very much, this was indeed my problem! I'll try to find a dynamic call (create a "matrix" heightxwidth) that can substitute the *fill* and come back to edit my comment with it. **EDIT:** `cells: [...Array(height).keys()].map(i => Array(width))` did the trick without causing the object problem